# Python Conciseness: Comparing string to multiple sets with return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, comparison

Something that I've never found a concise way to do is to compare a string with multiple sets, or perhaps one long one that gives some meaningful output. This is my current code:

```
def input():  
    text = input("Choose a number: ").lower()  
    if "1" in text or "one" in text: return 1  
    elif "2" in text or "two" in text: return 2  
    ... and so on...  
    elif "9" in text or "nine" in text: return 9
    else: return 0
```

My goal is to make it a bit more concise, considering how ugly it is right now.

Also, a little bit of a tag on question: is it faster to do this, or:

```
    if any(x in text for x in (["1", "one"])): return 1
```

Which one is considered more mainstream?

Sorry; my Python is really entry-level.

--- EDIT ---

Apologies for the confusion; I actually meant something more generalisable, such as for this:

```
def input():  
        text = input("Give an input: ").lower()  
        if any(x in text for x in (["eggplant", "emoji", "purple"])): return 1  
        elif any(x in text for x in (["tomato", "red", "tomatina"])): return 2  
        ... and so on...  
        elif any(x in text for x in (["lettuce", "green", "avatar"])): return 9
        else: return 0
```

Comment: Maybe regex? 
In addition, the input may be only a number or a digit (not a "phrase") ? can you make those assumptions?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't my original code; I just used a format that expressed what I meant. The input is going to be a string. I apologise for my lack of python expertise, but I don't really know how to use regex; could you possibly give me a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the regularity of your queries, you could use some kind of looping:

```
for i, s in enumerate('one two three four ... nine'.split(), 1):
  if str(i) in text or s in text:
    return i
return 0
```

Comment: Nice answer, however, you should check `str(i) in text` not `i in text`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Done, had that in my first version :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a normalization function for that:

```
_NORMALIZE_DICT = {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    ...
}

def normalize(test):
    return _NORMALIZE_DICT.get(test.lower(), test)
```

and then

```
def input():  
    text = normalize(input("Choose a number: "))
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

Comment: This is not exactly what they want. They are testing with `in` not `==`. If `text` is `'something 1'` for example, OP's code will return `1`.

Comment: I'll go clarify my original post; sorry for the confusion. Thanks @MosesKoledoye